# Javascript intercept requests and use a cached copy on my VPS

Tags: javascript, caching, interceptor

I like to prototype stuff in my browser -- using Jquery/similar to modify the DOM, load up scripts, images, css, etc without ever touching a text editor or unix shell.

Is there anything I can install on a VPS that will simply download a copy of any file on the web that I ask for from a particular script, so the next time I request it, it will be served from my VPS rather than hitting the origin again? Obviously the browser caches most things already, but the difference is that I want OTHER users on OTHER machines to get the cached copy on my VPS -- but this is irrelevant to the design --

For example:

```
require("library-that-checks-for-a-copy-on-my-VPS");

//pulls it down from Flickr's servers
loadImageFromFlickr("flickr.com/kitty18.jpg");

//now there's a copy on my VPS, so it's pulled down from there instead
loadImageFromFlickr("flickr.com/kitty18.jpg");
```

I'm really unfamiliar with caching and the options seem daunting, so I'm specifically looking for something that doesn't require much configuration; my requirements seem simple enough -- this is just for development so it doesn't need to be optimizable.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just use an object to store the requests result against it's url. That way when you call `loadImageFromFlickr` the first line is something like this...

```
var cache = {};
function loadImageFromFlickr(url) {
  if (cache[url]) return cache[url];
  /* fetch the content */
  return (cache[url] = functionToGetContent(url));
}
```

If you want your copies to persist over sessions (ie, stay cached in between server restarts) then you should look at storing the content response in a `cache` folder that is structured according to the url key. Then you can retrieve from the file instead of returning whats in the cache object.

PS, more succinct `return (cache[url] ||= functionToGetContent(url))`